# 2pi factor in proof - does it depend on definition of the Fourier transform?

Tags: dirac-delta, fourier-transform

I use the following def. of the Fourier transform
$$
f(\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{\mathbb{R}_2} F(\vec{k}) 
  e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}dk^2
$$
and also
$$
\Delta_{\vec{x}}\int_{\mathbb{R}_2} F(\vec{k}) 
  e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}dk^2 = - \int_{\mathbb{R}_2}||\vec{k}||^2 
  F(\vec{k}) e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}dk^2
$$

Now I want to proof:
$$
||(I-a\Delta_{\vec{x}})^{l/2}f(\vec{x})||^2 = \big|\big|(I+a||\vec{k}||^2)^{l/2} 
  F(\vec{k})\big|\big|^2
$$
However, I am not sure if there is some factor $2\pi$ missing...

For the proof I have to use the Fourier representation of the dirac-distribution
$$
\delta(\vec{k}) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^\text{?}}\int_{\mathbb{R}_2} 
  e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}} dx^2
$$
But I am not sure about the power of $1/2\pi$. If you could tell me what power is correct, I could determine the possibly missing factor in the proof...

Can you help? (note that I have to use the non-unitary definition of the FT... this is what causes all the trouble)

Comment: you should use the unitary version $f(x) = FT^{-1}[F(\xi)](x) =  \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} F(\xi) e^{2 i \pi \xi . x} d\xi$ such that $FT^4 = (FT^{-1})^4 = I$

Comment: the thing is that I HAVE to use the non-unitary FT. Thats the problem! ;)

Comment: change of variable $k = 2\pi \xi$ (in $\mathbb{R}^2 : \ dk = (2\pi)^2 d \xi$)

Comment: Then it would be $$\delta(\vec{x})=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}$$ AND ALSO(??) $$\delta(\vec{k})=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}$$ ?

Comment: assuming the Fourier inversion theorem works well for (tempered) distributions, you have $FT[\delta(x)](\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \delta(x) e^{-2i \pi \xi. x} dx = 1$, so that $\delta(x) = FT^{-1}[1](\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{2i \pi \xi. x} d\xi$ (where this integral converges only in the sense of distributions), and hence $\delta(x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{i k . x} dk$

Comment: Nice! But what about the other way around: what about $\delta(\vec{k})$? I guess it must be the same? Or does the normalization change?

Comment: renaming $x$ in $k$ won't change the result

Comment: thats what I thought - thank you!